# Convert multiple doc types (xls, doc, gif, png) to pdf in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am looking for a way to do this within a ruby on rails app. Need to do this locally within my service as the data is sensitive, I cant use external web services to do this.

Most important is images of various types as this is what most people scan documents into.

Comment: Found this http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter not sure how good it is but might be worth a try

Answer (score 3):

Install LibreOffice and Unoconv in your server and run the command.

> unoconv -f pdf File.doc

If you want to perform it with only LibreOffice use,

> ./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf destination_path source_file_path/*.doc

Comment: Images are not showing after converted into pdf (I'm working on CentOS)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/)?

**EDIT**

There doesn't appear to be a single solution to this problem. There are related StackOverflow questions, though, that might be of some help. For instance:

- [Is it possible to convert an HTML document to Excel with multiple Worksheets/tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213702/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-html-document-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets-tabs), for instance, talks about using POI to generate Excel spreadsheets and using the Excel gem to read them.
- [Convert a .doc or .pdf to an image and display a thumbnail in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250/convert-a-doc-or-pdf-to-an-image-and-display-a-thumbnail-in-ruby) discusses using RMagick to convert a PDF to an image.

Comment: Yes, Prawn is a pdf generation tool, afaik it doesnt convert document types. For images I think there is a way I could use prawn, but I figured there would be something better suited for this.

Comment: Thanks, I saw those, neither seem to be what I want. I want to go to a pdf for the 2nd. And for the excel, I dont have control over those. My general use case is I have multiple document  types to be merged into one big pdf. pdftk has been good at merging multiple pdfs, but havent found a solution to include additional doc types.

Comment: ok it looks like imagemagick will convert various image types to pdf, so thats great, I only need to figure out word and excel if possible. Seems like I need to use either open office or microsoft stuff to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There now is a single solution to the problem. I work on the PDF Converter Services, so consider me biased, but I have recently written a blog post about how to convert common file types such as DOC, XLS, PPT, HTML etc to PDF (and many other file types) using Ruby. For details [see this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2013/03/use-ruby-on-rails-to-convert-merge-and.html).